# sql server connection with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc02q.jpg)When I try to choose my Data connection in Data grid view I get prompted that I am missing Packages.

It says:

> It has been detected that packages for SQL Server support are missing. Operations requiring SQL server will fail if you continue without installing those packages. **Please press OK to install the packages**

Comment: So...did you press OK?

Comment: I have never seen that message, is a third party datagrid?

Comment: can you please provide screen shot?

Comment: please push the button please :)

Answer (score 0):

VS 2019 can detect if packages are missing for certain functionality. In such a case it will ask the user if it is ok to install them. I'd agree